# Endnote app icon persists in Macbook launchpad after deleting all files

Tags: macbook-pro, launchpad

Please help with the above. I uninstalled the files but the icon won't go away! I tried the terminal, went into Applications and I can see both "EndNote Cite While You Write" and "EndNote X8" (without the .app in the end and with spaces between words, which is unusual) but when I try to remove with rm -rf, it says "files do not exist". How do I get rid of it , please?

Comment: Have a look at this answer.  It may help.  [Delete an app from the Launchpad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237459/120171)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, it was as simple as finding the app on Finder and dragging it to the recycle bin. Duh!

Answer (score 1):

In the future, try using AppCleaner (http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). The Mac way of removing apps is to just move them to the trash, but that almost always leaves junk behind. AppCleaner helps gather that junk and send it to the trash, too.

Disclaimer: I'm not employed or endorsed my FreeMacSoft, the developers of AppCleaner. I'm just a fan.

Good luck! :)